# if statement fails with variable from CoreData managed object

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, xcode4

I'm having some trouble with Managed Objects... imagine that.

Here is one real doozy, maybe someone can help.

So I have a managed object class called "Format" which is an entity. Anyway, it has a property called "slot" that's an NSNumber. Now the number can have values from zero to four, but if it does not have a value then I want the NSNumber object to be equal to "nil" as opposed to zero. I wasn't having any luck with that since evidently being zero is the same as being "nil." Ugh. (Is there a way to tell if the pointer is simply empty, "nil," as opposed to pointing to a zero value?)

At any rate, I tried a work-around which was to render the variable into text like so:

```
if(@"myFormat.slot" != @"(null)")
    NSLog(@"slot==%@",myFormat.slot);
```

But the problem is that I got this in my log:

```
slot==(null)
```

So, OK... what the heck? If @"myFormat.slot" == @"(null)" then how the heck is that if statement resolving...?!?!

I'm truly baffled now... please someone help me out.

Comment: OK i'm really tired. Obviously @"myformat.slot" is wrong, needs to be @"%@",myformat.slot... sigh. But I still would like the first question answered if possible. (Is there a way to tell if the pointer is simply empty, "nil," as opposed to pointing to a zero value?)

Comment: Well, back to square one... because:

Comment: NSString *asdf = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"slot==%@",myFormat.slot];
    NSLog(asdf);
    if(asdf != @"slot==(null)") {
        NSLog(@"slot==%@",myFormat.slot);

Comment: Results in the same problem. two slot==(null) on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't ever get a `nil` back from an attribute. Instead, you get a `[NSNull null]` object.

In Objective-C, `nil` and `null` are not interchangeable. When you see `nil` you are almost looking at a dereferenced pointer. `nil` is intended to convey that no object has been assigned to the symbol. `null` by contrast is the singleton instance of `[NSNull null]`. It is used as a placeholder to indicate that some ***value***, represented by an object, has not been set. In other words, a value of `nil` doesn't make sense in Objective-C.

In Core Data, relationships and attributes are not treated the same even though they both return objects. A relationship is a pointer to an external object and therefore can have a return `nil` if no object has been set on the other side of the relationship. An attribute is a ***value*** only held by an object and therefore is always represented by `[NSNull null]` if not set.

By default, all attributes with numerical value will return an NSNumber object initialized to zero. If you remove the default you get `[NSNull null]`.

However, since `[NSNull null]` is a singleton you can use a simple pointer comparison to check for it e.g.

```
if (myMo.numericalAttribute == [NSNull null])...
```

However, that is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

This `if(@"myFormat.slot" != @"(null)")` is always true, because `@"myString"` creates an autoreleased string. Therefore you are checking the addresses of to different autorelease strings and (surprise) they are different.

Have you tried something like this:

```
if ([myNumber isEqualTo: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0]]) self.myNumber = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing the contents of 2 `NSString` objects, use the `isEqual:` method or, if you need to perform a Unicode-based comparison of strings, use `isEqualToString:`.

If you want to set `myFormat.slot` to `nil`, do this:

```
myFormat.slot = nil;
```

To set the value of the `slot` attribute to zero:

```
myFormat.slot = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
```

To compare values wrapped in `NSNumber`s (e.g. check if your slot is equal to the 0 integer value), do this:

```
if ([myFormat.slot intValue] == 0) { // primitive type comparison
    //... 
}
```

or this:

```
if ([myFormat.slot isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) { // object comparison
    //... 
}
```

but **NOT THIS**:

```
if (myFormat.slot == 0) { // pointer comparison!! 
    //... 
}
```

To check if `slot` is empty (nil):

```
if (myFormat.slot == nil) {
    //...
}
```

Keep in mind: Core Data standard attributes are always mapped to non-primitive values (NSString, NSDate, NSNumber). Always use `isEqual:`, `compare:` & friends when comparing objects' values. The `==` operator performs *pointer* comparison when you use it with non-primitives.