# Strange behaviour with Xcode and iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've stumbled upon what seems like an impossible situation with an iphone app. I have three boolean variables which all are NO (false) and then I test in an if statement whether they is at least one of them as YES (true).

Well, as you can see in the screenshot, the debugger steps inside the if clause and eventually adds the value of `BOTTOM_HEIGHT` to the height variable. This seems absolutely backwards, have I found a quantum boolean or something? (jk)

Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I have already tried to clear the project, Reset the contents and settings of the simulator and even deleted the Derived Data from the xcode build folder in case it was caching old code and nothing seems to work.

----- Update ------

Ok, it seems that it works ok but the variables after debugging with the ideas provided by Maverick1st aren't being reported correctly and hasAvatar, hasRating and haOpinions are always shown as NO. I've figured out that the problem with the result being incorrect is on the `offer` which is a `NSManagedObject` is never null despite setting as null when I initialize the object and when I log it I get this:

```
2011-09-22 10:00:03.889 11870.com[2613:207] offer: (null)
```

This object gets initialized in a separate project in the workspace that gets added as a static library and I think I've deleted the library's build files so that they get generated again. In fact, I know it since otherwise it would give me a compilation error since on previous version of the library we didn't have the offer property.

I'm gonna do further investigation to see if I find why is this happening.

PS: can someone reedit my post, since it doesn't let me post images yet, thanks

Comment: did you try to log height before and after if state. It seems they are both equal.

Comment: Before it has a value of 75 and after it has a value of 101 (with `OFFER_HEIGHT` being 26)

Comment: Have you run static analysis on this file? Maybe make clean then rebuild. I've noticed that sometimes straight recompilation doesn't correctly flush some auxiliary file, resulting in bad behavior.

Comment: If clean is not enough you can also delete your complete build folder. As matthias said it could be that you have "artifacts" of old code in your build folder.

Comment: If this is a release build, optimization may lead to the position shown in the debugger being wrong.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, I tried deleting the build folders with no effect. I thought about the debugger showing the wrong lines but the side effects of the process are influenced by this strange behavior.
@matthias what do you mean by static analysis?

Comment: I mean the process described at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html

It recompiles the code in a way that clang can run intelligent analysis; while I don't expect it to find something you did wrong, this recompilation sometimes takes care of artifacts, and can show areas that are causing problems, including the one in the question.

Comment: A ok, I knew it simply as "Analyze" from xcode's menu :) It's quite a helpful tool, although in this case it was something different, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after further investigation I found that there were several problems.

- With the quantum booleans the debugger for the simulator was going "bananas" when running the release build. When running on debug it works as expected.
- The offers never being null turned to be a problem with CoreData returning a `NSNull` object. I found the solution here: [if statement fails with variable from CoreData managed object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581727)
- Another problem I didn't report is that the height of the cell weren't correct but I just reduced one of the measures used to calculate the total height as a workaround since it looks like the offset was constant.

Thanks for all the responses, it was really helpful.

PS: Should I select this answer as correct or wait for voting? Quite new poster here :)

---

Update:

I finally got to the source of the issue for the third problem ans why it was returning a reference to [NSNull null] instead of nil as it does with the rest of relationships in CodeData.

The secondary project that handles the DAO operations had no target and the target dependency got lost somehow when changing from Xcode 3.2 to Xcode 4.0 a couple of months back. It wasn't giving me a problem with the selector since the model was being copied in a different way.

Well, apparently CodeData has 2 different null states for objects: `NSNull` for when the object has not been set and nil when you give the value nil (Which I tent to do in the parse and hence it didn't return `NSNull` before)

Anywho, all seems to be working more or less as expected.

Comment: If u think an answer of one of us was helpful or pushed you into the right direction you are free to upvote the answer. Of course you are also free to mark the correct answer as such. But since i am also quite new here, i dont know if you can mark your own answer as the correct one. But i see no reason why it should not be possible. :)
It would be nice though, if you could explain why your quantum boolean went bananas in the release build and not in the debug build. That would be interesting to know (at least for me). 
greets.
Mav.

Comment: The reason it went crazy I think is, as mentioned in the comments in the original question, because of the optimizations that xcode does that can result in undesired outputs. I guess it works as expected since there is a reason you have two types of builds (So much easier to debug on Android, but don't want to troll about it here)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried formulating explicitly with (hasEdit == YES)-terms?

Comment: Yeah, I even tried to have them in separate if clauses like this: if(hasRating == YES) and all three clauses get executed even though they all three are false

Comment: Try setting up an intermediate variable, like

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the statement

```
if(hasRating ││ hasAvatars ││ hasOpinions)
```

as seperate if statements.

---------Edit----------

Ok, so maybe it will work like this way. This is at least how i do those kind of things.

```
BOOL b_oneOfTheThreeIsTrue;

if(hasRating)
    b_oneOfTheThreeIsTrue = true;
if(hasAvatars)
    b_oneOfTheThreeIsTrue = true;
if(hasOpinions)
    b_oneOfTheThreeIsTrue = true;
```

Still good to debug and you can check for the one variable in your if statement.

```
if(b_oneOfTheThreeIsTrue)
    doSomething;
```

Comment: Ok, in this fashion it kind of works but they are not equivalent. The cascading if statement is equivalent to `if(hasRating && hasAvatars && hasOpinions)` gonna see if I can make it work somehow with a variant of this.

Comment: hmmm, you are right. I will think of how you can accomplish this.

Comment: Wow, this is getting silly. I tried your last proposed solution and `b_oneOfTheThreeIsTrue` was YES after setting it's value as NO by default and running the three is clauses with all three tests variables being NO. Gonna try to set the default values of the variables since I've just noticed that the variables do not appear in the debug details window.